# Using pretrained LSTM and Bert Models in CPU Only Environment - How to speed up Predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, lstm, bert

I have trained two text classification models using GPU on Azure. The models are the following

1. Bert (ktrain)
2. Lstm Word2Vec (tensorflow)

Exaples of the code can be found here: [nlp](https://github.com/lukasgarbas/nlp-text-emotion)

I saved the models into files (.h5) for later use. The files are big e.g. 27,613kb for the lstm and 1.2 gb for bert.

I loaded the models and in a computer where only CPU is available. They both work fine but the `model.predict(text)` function is super slow predicting the class of the text e.g. on average 1 tweet sized message per second.

Adding GPU on the computer is not an option. I wonder if there is another way to make it run faster? e.g. train the models in a different way (without compromising accuracy) or save the model in a different file format?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to speed up the actual prediction time of the exact same model. The fastest way I can think of is loading the model once, and then predicting in batches. Do you do `with torch.no_grad()` and set `model.eval()`?

Comment: @N.Kiefer the question specifies that the models are for tensorflow (`ktrain` is a `tf.keras` wrapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

- Optimize tensorflow for your specific CPU. Sometimes the official versions of tensorflow are not compiled with support for some instruction sets (e.g. SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, FMA). Usually, there is a tensorflow runtime warning message stating so. This prevents some computations to take place in parallel. You can either download a version that is optimized for your CPU (e.g. [from intel](https://medium.com/@mychen76/build-tensorflow-to-get-free-performance-increase-from-cpu-839f4e1187ee)) or you can [compile tensorflow yourself](https://syslog.ravelin.com/compiling-tensorflow-to-use-all-available-cpu-instructions-607945795b5c).
- Prune the model. BERT is a multi-head attention model, and it is possible to remove some of its attention heads while retaining most of the quality. [Here](https://blog.rasa.com/pruning-bert-to-accelerate-inference/)'s a blog post that shows how to do it for tensorflow.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. While researching this particular problem I came across TensorFlow Serving. Do you think this could help? https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple

Comment: Tensorflow serving is just for exposing your model as a web service. The tensorflow runtime is the same, so you will not get better performance just for using tensorflow serving.